# Phing property: fallback from environment variable to property file

Tags: phing, fallback

Is there an elegant way of determining a value for a property?
For example, I'd like to allow a property to be read from a file, but also to be grabbed from an environment variable. If the environment variable is present, I'd like to prioritize it over the file's value.

Here's what I have (with the example property `deploy.destination`):

```
<property environment="env" />
<if>
    <isset property="env.DEPLOY_DEST" />
    <then>
        <property name="deploy.destination" refid="env.DEPLOY_DEST"/>
    </then>
</if>
<property file="build.properties"/>
```

However, it's fairly bulky (especially for more than more property).

Is there a way I can do something like this?

```
<property environment="env" />
<property name="deploy.destination" refid="env.DEPLOY_DEST"/>
<property file="build.properties"/>
```

With this example, it fails if `env.DEPLOY_DEST` is not set.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Given your statement:

> If the environment variable is present, I'd like to prioritize it over the file's value.

you can do

```
<property environment="env" />
<if>
    <available file="custom.properties"/>
    <then>
        <property file="custom.properties" override="false"/>
    </then>
</if>
```

The key shall be **override="false"** to allow env property values to stay.

Comment: I guess a critical details is that environment variables are named differently than the variables in the properties file.


For example, the environment variable is `DEPLOY_DEST`, while the same variable is called `deploy.destination` in the properties file. I'm assuming that this is the standard?

Comment: De facto standard, you are right on that. Using a mapper you should be able to get to the point.

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables are widely used in CI/CD platforms, if this is your case maybe the following will be useful.

First I show you my buildfile **build.xml**:

```
<project name="Demo" default="deployment">

    <target name="deployment">
        <property file="build.properties.ini"/>
        <echo message="Your host is: ${destination}"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

My propertyfile **build.properties.ini**:

```
destination = localhost
```

If we execute the only target in our buildfile, `$ phing deployment`, the output will be the expected one:

```
$ phing deployment
[echo] Your host is: localhost
```

Now execute the following `$ phing deployment -Ddestination=example.com`, the output is:

```
$ phing deployment -Ddestination=example.com
[echo] Your host is: example.com
```

As you can see my **buildfile** and **propertyfile** remain unchanged.  however I was capable change the value of  `destination` property, this is because when properties are set as a *command line argument* they have higher priority than properties declared in a *property file*.

To conclude:

```
// Use the following in development
$ phing deployment

// And override "destination" in your CI/CD config
$ phing deployment -Ddestination=$DEPLOY_DEST
```

Source: https://www.phing.info/phing/guide/en/output/chunkhtml/ch04s03.html